# How to detect changes for the inner elements of an ASP.NET AJAX control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

Within a custom ASP.NET AJAX control, I'm trying to get all of the inner inputs of the element that represents the container, and detect their changes.

The following works only in IE 9 and FF:

```
if (this.get_watchChanges()) {
    $(this.get_element()).find(":input").change(function() {
         //mark dirty
    });
}
```

Looking for input elements with the type of text and checkbox is not working for me at all.

What's a good cross-browser way to detect a change for inner elements of a parent element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding something targeting the various types of controls (since I was using Telerik).  I can't post the result, but I ended up doing something like:

```
$(".RadDatePicker").each(function() { /* attach to date change event */ });
```

And so on for each control (targeting them by their CSS class.  The complexity came because of the ASP.NET AJAX framework, and how the JavaScript APIs worked.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is quite old, just stumbled on it and thought I'd through something up for the next guy.  Would something like this work?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var isDirty = false;
   $(document).ready(function() {
      isDirty = false;
      $("input, input[@type=checkbox]").change(function() {
         isDirty = true;
      });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: It might, but what I was running into was I was using Telerik controls, and some of those controls were throwing me off.  I ended up instead targeting each control specifically.  Some of the reasons were too that, for instance, with their date picker control, a button triggers a calendar and changes the associated text box, which does not fire the change event, so I had to get very specific with my change handling.  In most scenarios, what you have is probably sufficient.